# Тестирование swing приложений

Tags: java, swing, тестирование

Есть приложение java web start, для подключении использую [эту библиотеку](http://jnlp.sourceforge.net/netx/).

Подключение происходит следующим образом

```
JNLPRuntime.setTrustAll(true);
JNLPRuntime.setAllowRedirect(true);
JNLPRuntime.setDebug(true);
JNLPRuntime.setForksAllowed(false);
JNLPRuntime.setSecurityEnabled(false);
JNLPRuntime.setVerify(true);
JNLPRuntime.initialize(true);
logger.debug("Runtime init has done.");
Launcher launcher = new Launcher(false);
try {
    ApplicationInstance app = launcher.launch(new URL(url));
    logger.debug("connected to " + app);
}
```

Приложение стартует, все хорошо.

Далее я хочу тестировать его библиотекой [fest](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fest/).

Дальше по коду я создаю робота, который будет делать действия в данном приложении

```
org.fest.swing.core.Robot currentRobot = BasicRobot.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy();
```

**Вопросы**

1. Как робот узнает, что ему надо "прицепиться" к данному аппликейшену? Ведь в робот никакой информации о приложении не приходит.
2. Сама ошибка - при старте приложения, когда я хочу найти какой-либо компонент, мне выдает ошибку - `Unable to find component using matcher` и выдает такой `stacktrace`:

> Component hierarchy:
>
> javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame[name='frame0', title='',
>   enabled=true, visible=false, showing=false]
>   javax.swing.JWindow[name='win0']
>       javax.swing.JRootPane[]
>         javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
>         javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
>           javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.contentPane']   javax.swing.JWindow[name='win1']
>       javax.swing.JRootPane[]
>         javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
>         javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
>           javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.contentPane']   javax.swing.JWindow[name='win2']
>       javax.swing.JRootPane[]
>         javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
>         javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
>           javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.contentPane']   javax.swing.JWindow[name='win3']
>       javax.swing.JRootPane[]
>         javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
>         javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
>           javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.contentPane']
>
> at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.componentNotFound(BasicComponentFinder.java:271)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.find(BasicComponentFinder.java:260)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.find(BasicComponentFinder.java:179)

Соответственно, такой иерархии я не нахожу в приложении, которое тестируется.

P.S. каждый компонент выводу в логгер, и вижу, что каждый компонент из данной иерархии имеет координаты 0,0 и размеры 0x0, соответственно даже скриншот с компонента взять никак не получается

Откуда берется эта иерархия?